# Text jumps right to center when keyboard toggled

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecycleView` in which I visualize some text. The text is entered through an `EditText` view in the bottom. The `RecycleView` contains a `TextView` which is has the text centered.

I have also a function that detects if the keyboard is visualised. When the keyboard is visualised, then some layout parameters are changed so that the `EditText` looks good.  I also have a smooth scroll to the last position of the `RecycleView`.

When I reopen the keyboard again, the text is first drawn to the left of the screen. If I swipe, the text is re-aligned to center. That is very disturbing and I always want the text to be centered. I probably miss something when changing the parameters of the layouts.

KeyBoard openedListener:

```
// Function to see of keyboard is opened or not.
private void detectKeyBoard(){
    final ConstraintLayout rootView = findViewById(R.id.activity_root);
    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            float heightDiff = rootView.getRootView().getHeight() - rootView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
            if (!isRefSet){
                refDiff = heightDiff;
                isRefSet = true;
            }
            if (heightDiff > refDiff) {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        0);
                params.weight = wRSmall;

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams eParams = new
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        0);
                eParams.weight = wESmall;
                mLinearInput.setLayoutParams(eParams);
                if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        0);
                params.weight = wRStart;
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams eParams = new
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        0);
                eParams.weight = wEStart;
                mLinearInput.setLayoutParams(eParams);
                if (mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

xml for RecycleView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/activity_root"
tools:context="com.example.erikbylow.autoflash.TranslateActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/translate_linear"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/translate_recycle"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linear_input"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:id="@+id/source_input"
            android:hint="Type text to translate"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/source_input"
            android:text="Translate"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="startTranslate"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

TextView for Adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/active_text_size"
    android:id="@+id/adapter_textview"/>
```

[image]

After swiping it is re-aligned:

[image]

EDIT: It did not work to remove `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` in the recycle xml part.

Further, if the screen is full without the keyboard being opened, the text is moved to the right:
[image]

Comment: remove `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` from your recyclerview item xml

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you comment the detectKeyBoard() function? Just to check if the same problem exists or not?

Comment: The problem remains, so maybe one should do something in the layoutmanager?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess -

I see that you are creating a new `LayoutParams` object and assign it to your `mRecyclerView` and `mLinearInput`.

As far as I know, this new LayoutParam object will replace what you have set in XML, including layout_gravity, **layout_weight**, etc.

Try getting existing LayoutParams from mRecyclerView and mLinearInput, and modify their values instead.

Cannot advise much because I do not really understand the reason behind resetting layout params in your case.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable but the problem remains even if I comment out the `detectKeyboard`. The reason to change the weights is that the `EditText` gets to small. There are standard commands for dealing with this type of problem, but for me it did not work. Therefore I chose to change the weights.